Avahi: .local domains only accessible for a few minutes
On a few Linux devices (including an Android phone running Termux) I have installed Avahi and it works, but the internal .local address is only visible for a few minutes. After that few minutes when the .local address is not visible anymore, it is still available on the server itself when I do a check with mdns-scan, but not outside the device.
It does work in an Ubuntu 22.04 installation (including the Raspberry Pi), but not on Rocky Linux and Termux (subsystem under Android not using Android root). And my Macbook also keeps exporting its .local domain, but not by Avahi. But in all cases the avahi-daemon.conf look the same except for the host-name which is exported correctly in all cases, except for a limited amount of time for the latter two Linux environments. However, running `mdns-scan' on the server itself which stops exporting after a few minutes, still keeps recognizing its own hostname.
I have even switched off ipv6 and any other networks than wifi on Termux.
:~$ mdns-scan 
+ nothingphone._ssh._tcp.local
+ nothingphone._sftp-ssh._tcp.local
+ adb-000481423000975._adb._tcp.local
+ mymacbook._ssh._tcp.local
+ mymacbook._sftp-ssh._tcp.local
+ mymacbook._rfb._tcp.local
+ <hexstring>-supportsRP-19._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local
+ iPad Air 2._companion-link._tcp.local
^Cowsing ... -     (aborted by Ctrl+C)

which tells that nothingphone avahi is still active but not discoverable outside the device a few minutes after restarting avahi-daemon.
What is stopping this service ?
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

[server]
host-name=nothingphone
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=no
allow-interfaces=wlan0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no
#reflect-filters=_airplay._tcp.local,_raop._tcp.local

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
#rlimit-core=0
#rlimit-data=8388608
#rlimit-fsize=0
#rlimit-nofile=768
#rlimit-stack=8388608
#rlimit-nproc=3

